# Why is DT1[DT2][, value1-value] faster than DT1[DT2, value1-value] on data.table with fewer columns?

Tags: r, data.table

*This is related to this question ([Can I access repeated column names in `j` in a data.table join?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17718842/1900520)), that was asked because I assumed that the opposite to this was true.*

#### data.table with just 2 columns:

Suppose you wish to join two `data.tables` and then perform a simple operation on two joined columns, this can be done either in one or two calls to `.[`:

```
N = 1000000
DT1 = data.table(name = 1:N, value = rnorm(N))
DT2 = data.table(name = 1:N, value1 = rnorm(N))
setkey(DT1, name)

system.time({x = DT1[DT2, value1 - value]})     # One Step

system.time({x = DT1[DT2][, value1 - value]})   # Two Step
```

It turns out that making two calls - **doing the join first, and then doing the subtraction - is noticeably quicker than all in one go**.

```
> system.time({x = DT1[DT2, value1 - value]})
   user  system elapsed 
   0.67    0.00    0.67 
> system.time({x = DT1[DT2][, value1 - value]})
   user  system elapsed 
   0.14    0.01    0.16
```

Why is this?

#### data.table with *many* columns:

If you put a LOT of columns in to the `data.table` then you do eventually find that the one step approach is quicker - presumably because `data.table` only uses the columns you reference in `j`.

```
N = 1000000
DT1 = data.table(name = 1:N, value = rnorm(N))[, (letters) := pi][, (LETTERS) := pi][, (month.abb) := pi]
DT2 = data.table(name = 1:N, value1 = rnorm(N))[, (letters) := pi][, (LETTERS) := pi][, (month.abb) := pi]
setkey(DT1, name)
system.time({x = DT1[DT2, value1 - value]})
system.time({x = DT1[DT2][, value1 - value]})

> system.time({x = DT1[DT2, value1 - value]})
   user  system elapsed 
   0.89    0.02    0.90 
> system.time({x = DT1[DT2][, value1 - value]})
   user  system elapsed 
   1.64    0.16    1.81
```

Comment: I changed the title to something more direct. Hope it's alright.

Comment: I just want to confirm that you realize (not obvious from OP) that there is a hidden `by` in the first case and the two expressions give very different results in general

Comment: the two *types of expressions

Comment: @eddi I don't think I did realise - care to expand on that?

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16093289/data-table-join-and-j-expression-unexpected-behavior) and the follow up [mailing list discussion](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/changing-data-table-by-without-by-syntax-to-require-a-quot-by-quot-td4664770.html). Expectation is that this behavior will become explicit in the future making the difference obvious.

Comment: The mailing list in particular has a couple of really good examples from @MatthewDowle highlighting the difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is due to the repeated subsetting `DT1[DT2, value1-value]` makes for every `name` in `DT2`. That is, you've to perform a `j` operation for each `i` here, as opposed to just one `j` operation after the `join`. This becomes quite costly with 1e6 unique entries. That is, `[.data.table` becomes significant and noticeable.

```
DT1[DT2][, value1-value] # similar to rowSums
DT1[DT2, value1-value]
```

In the first case, `DT1[DT2]`, you perform the `join` first, and it is *really* fast. Of course, with more columns, as you show, you'll see a difference. But the point is performing the join *once*. But in the second case, you're grouping DT1 by DT2's name and for every one of them you're computing the difference. That is, you're subsetting `DT1` for each value of `DT2` - one 'j' operation per subset! You can see this better by just running this:

```
Rprof()
t1 <- DT1[DT2, value1-value]
Rprof(NULL)
summaryRprof()

# $by.self
#                self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
# "[.data.table"      0.96    97.96       0.98    100.00
# "-"                 0.02     2.04       0.02      2.04

Rprof()
t2 <- DT1[DT2][, value1-value]
Rprof(NULL)
summaryRprof()

# $by.self
#                self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
# "[.data.table"      0.22    84.62       0.26    100.00
# "-"                 0.02     7.69       0.02      7.69
# "is.unsorted"       0.02     7.69       0.02      7.69
```

This overhead in repeated subsetting seems to be overcome when you've too many columns and the `join` on many columns overtakes as the time-consuming operation. You can probably check this out yourself by profiling the other code.

Comment: brilliant question + answer